# Room. The first query returns null value

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

In my Android project I use Room library for working with SQLite database. I use my database for purpose of keeping of country telephone codes. My database is preloaded with two coutries (watch  **populateDatabaseWithCountryCodes(dao: PhoneCodeDao)** function) ;

```
@Database(entities = [CountryCode::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun createPhoneCodeDao(): PhoneCodeDao

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
        val tempInstance = INSTANCE
        if (tempInstance != null) {
            return tempInstance
        }
        synchronized(this) {
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "database"
            ).addCallback(PrepopulationCallback)
                .build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            return instance
        }
    }
}

object PrepopulationCallback : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        super.onCreate(db)
        INSTANCE?.let { database ->
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                populateDatabaseWithCountryCodes(database.createPhoneCodeDao())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun populateDatabaseWithCountryCodes(dao: PhoneCodeDao) {
        val spainPhoneCode = CountryCode(0, "Spain", 34)
        val rusPhoneCode = CountryCode(1, "Russia", 7)
        val list = LinkedList<CountryCode>()
        list.add(spainPhoneCode)
        list.add(rusPhoneCode)
        dao.insertAllCountryCodes(list)
    }
}
}
```

**CountryCode entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "country_code")
data class CountryCode(
@SerializedName("order")
@ColumnInfo(name = "order_list") val order: Int,
@SerializedName("name")
@ColumnInfo(name = "country_name_eng") val name: String,
@SerializedName("phone_code")
@ColumnInfo(name = "phone_code") val phoneCode: Int
) {
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Long = 0
}
```

**DAO interface**

```
@Dao
interface PhoneCodeDao {

@Insert
fun insertAllCountryCodes(list: List<CountryCode>)

@Query("SELECT phone_code FROM country_code WHERE order_list = :order")
fun selectCountryCodeByOrder(order: Int): Int

}
```

In my app I select country code by order (watch function **selectCountryCodeByOrder(order: Int): Int**). I invoke this function asynchronously inside async{} coroutine. But I have a quite strange bug: **When after installation I make first launch of my app on the device and make query - the result of query is 0 (it means that there is no results). But on the next queries and during next launches it works brilliantly - it returns 7 and 34 accordingly to order parameter.** So I'm very confused with that bug. Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: i thing is because you are populating the data asynchronously try to execute the call back inside `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute { //here } `

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's probably querying the database when its empty. so the best way to solve this is to return a LiveData instead of a primitive int. then the LiveData will take care of updating the UI when the database is populated.

```
 @Query("SELECT phone_code FROM country_code WHERE order_list = :order")
fun selectCountryCodeByOrder(order: Int): LiveData<SomeType>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a surprise, the database is pre-populated asynchronously, and you are not notified of when the data is actually inserted.

You can check in the official AAC samples, specifically the `BasicSample` that to be notified:

- [You need to have a `LiveData<Boolean>` that is signalled by the `RoomDatabase.Callback`.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/078b35367cf9e971b7cfe57b302054e60b56abe6/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/db/AppDatabase.java)

.

```
private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> mIsDatabaseCreated = new MutableLiveData<>();

public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context, final AppExecutors executors) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = buildDatabase(context.getApplicationContext(), executors);
                sInstance.updateDatabaseCreated(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}

/**
 * Build the database. {@link Builder#build()} only sets up the database configuration and
 * creates a new instance of the database.
 * The SQLite database is only created when it's accessed for the first time.
 */
private static AppDatabase buildDatabase(final Context appContext,
        final AppExecutors executors) {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
            .addCallback(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                    super.onCreate(db);
                    executors.diskIO().execute(() -> {
                        // ...create the database here

                        // notify that the database was created and it's ready to be used
                        database.setDatabaseCreated();
                    });
                }
            })
        .build();
}

/**
 * Check whether the database already exists and expose it via {@link #getDatabaseCreated()}
 */
private void updateDatabaseCreated(final Context context) {
    if (context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).exists()) {
        setDatabaseCreated();
    }
}

private void setDatabaseCreated(){
    mIsDatabaseCreated.postValue(true);
}
```

- [You need a `MediatorLiveData` to consume the `0` result for when the results are not yet available](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/078b35367cf9e971b7cfe57b302054e60b56abe6/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/DataRepository.java#L19-L30)

  ```
  mObservableProducts.addSource(mDatabase.productDao().loadAllProducts(),
          productEntities -> {
              if (mDatabase.getDatabaseCreated().getValue() != null) {
                  mObservableProducts.postValue(productEntities);
              }
          });
  ```
- You can expose the results as `LiveData<...>` so that you will be notified when the results are actually there

Comment: any idea how to do this with Kotlin coroutines